# Values Separated in Excel

Tags: r, excel

I have a dataframe in R which contains values like:

```
Sales officer        2      3
Therapy Specialist   4      9
Quality,Assurance    3      5
Training Manager     5      4
```

But when I write this data into Excel, the 3rd row  `Quality,Assurance` is treated separately i.e Excel looks like this:

```
Sales officer        2      3
Therapy Specialist   4      9
Quality          Assurance  3      5
Training Manager     5      4
```

This is just a sample example. I have a lot of such fields which have commas due to which they are shifted by one column while writing in Excel.

How to stop this?

Comment: How are you writing it to excel?  please show the code.

Comment: @G5W  write.table(df, file = "Clustering.csv",sep = ", ",row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)

Comment: Oddly,  I used exactly your `write.table` statement  and got a correctly working csv file. It had correctly put quotes around `Quality, Assurance` and so it appeared in a single column in Excel.

Comment: I notice that you are appending to the file.  Is it possible that you have an older incorrectly formatted file that you are appending,  it is being correctly written but you are still seeing the older incorrect data?

Comment: @G5W Even if I make append=False it does not put them in same cell. I have no idea how did it work for you. Is it possible that we might have different settings for excel? Can you share your exact code so that I can test it on my machine

Comment: Please delete the file clustering.csv before running this. 

`df = read.table(text="'Sales officer'        2      3
'Therapy Specialist'   4      9
'Quality,Assurance'    3      5
'Training Manager'     5      4",
header=FALSE);

write.table(df, file = "Clustering.csv",sep = ", ",row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)`

Comment: @G5W Its coming in different cell in my machine. I do not know how to fix this and this is vry important.

Comment: Try opening the csv file in a text editor (like notepad or Notepad++).  Are the job titles in quotes?

Comment: @G5W No they are not in quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148690/discussion-between-g5w-and-praveen-singh).

Comment: You say your data aren't quoted when you open them notepad. That seems strange. Try setting `quote = TRUE` in `write.table`, that should force double quoyes around your strings. (But that's also supposed to be the default behavior)

Comment: @G5W I found something. Like you know I am appending table after tables. So If i make append=false then it works perfectly fine. All the strings with comma are considered as one and are represented in one colmun but when i make append=true following error comes and strings like Quality, Assurance are separated:                                
 Warning message:
In write.table(df, file = "Clustering.csv", sep = ", ", row.names = FALSE,  :
  appending column names to file

Comment: @Benjamin Is there any way by which instead of appending to same sheet I could create a new sheet (in same file)  for each table and put each new table into a different sheet

Comment: Not with `write.table` but you could try the `WriteXLS` package. (As long as your strings don't contain linebreaks)

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2007, you can use fixed width to format data.
**Steps**

- click Data
- click Text to column (in Data Tools Ribbon)
- select fixed width

Then you get your data as is

Comment: But this can be done only after creating an excel file. I am asking how to do that while writing the data from R to excel. For instance I use this command "write.table(df, file = "Clustering.csv",sep = ", ",row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)" in R to create the file and it automatically shows Quality and assurance separated. What to do to prevent this?

Comment: use tab separator, modify your code:  sep="\t"

Comment: That fits all the three cells into one cell of that row. I do not want that. I want that Quality,Assurance should come in one cell rather than two.

Comment: Can you provide your complete code : how to read the strings -how to write them, to know where the problem.

Comment: When I am printing it on R console it is showing correctly just that while wrting it separate strings with comma in between

Comment: Don't use comma as a separator,for your strings contains comma. Use other char may be colon: , tab. when you use sep="" it's considered as a tab delimiter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148685/discussion-between-praveen-singh-and-m-hassan).